# Exclude folders in rsnapshot containing docker except docker/volumes

Tags: rsnapshot

I configured rsnapshot, to exclude all foders containing the string `docker/` in its path in the file `rsnapshot_exclude`

```
docker/*
```

but now I want to **include** one particular folder:

```
/var/lib/docker/volumes/
```

How do I define this in `rsnapshot.conf`?

maybe define like this somehow?

```
docker/(?!volumes))
```

Answer (score 1):

As `rsnapshot` uses `rsync` and passes the exclude rules to it, you can specifically include directories/files by using a '`+`' (include) rule.

The first rule that applies is acted on, so simply add a line

```
+ /var/lib/docker/volumes/
```

ABOVE your other rule.

From the rsync documentation:

> **Filter Rules**
>
> ...
>
> As the list of files/directories to transfer is built, rsync checks each name to be transferred against the list of include/exclude patterns in turn, and the first matching pattern is acted on: if it is an exclude pattern, then that file is skipped; if it is an include pattern then that filename is not skipped; if no matching pattern is found, then the filename is not skipped.